# ¿Es necesario el cierre inmediato de las preguntas mal formuladas de un nuevo miembro?¿Por qué no dar el lapso suficiente para reflexionar?

Tags: discusión

No soy muy afín al meta, pero de ves en cuando surgen dudas como esta.

Desde que formo parte de la comunidad suelo ver muchas preguntas mal formuladas por nuevos miembros y a su vez esos nuevos miembros preguntan sin siquiera tomarse la molestia de ir a [tour] o a [ask]. Siempre suelo aconsejarles que se tomen esa molestia de leerlos.

La falta de conocimiento de esa información implica que ellos cometan ese tipo de errores *(si se permite llamarlo así)*. Sinceramente cansa, pero son usuarios nuevos, es entendible que es necesario guiarlos.

Hace minutos un nuevo usuario hizo la siguiente [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460472/programa-en-si-la-bas), sin siquiera terminar de leer uno ya se da cuenta de la calidad de la misma. Traté de darle un consejo a modo de guía el cual espero lo tome en cuenta y decida editar o en el mejor de los casos cerrar la pregunta. Unos 5 o 6 minutos después, otro usuario comenta apoyando el cierre de la pregunta.

Casos como estos se leen, haciendo un análisis rápido de la pregunta y se suelen apoyar/rechazar, pero:

Siendo él un usuario nuevo, ¿no seria mejor no apresurarse con los reportes y darle la posibilidad de cierre a el mismo? claro, previa lectura de los enlaces correspondientes. Y es simple saberlo, tenemos las medallas correspondientes para guiarnos si esa persona esta o no enterada de como funciona el sitio.

Sé que hay que ser estrictos, pero también tolerantes en algunos casos, la comunidad es grande, y cada día crece mas, pero me da la sensación(es un dato que desconozco, no se si es un dato generalmente conocido) de que muchas personas, solo por obtener un rechazo tan tajante respecto a sus dudas ya no suelen frecuentar el sitio para formular nuevas preguntas, solo la visitan como un usuario *"al paso"*.

Comment: Hay preguntas y hay _preguntas_. Hay veces que los usuarios nuevos hacen preguntas que no se ajustan a los principios del sitio y que no habría manera de corregirlas para que se ajusten (p.e. la pregunta enlazada no se ajusta porque pide ayuda con tarea escolar sin mostrar esfuerzo/trabajo realizado, incluso si lo pusiera, la pregunta sería muy amplia porque son múltiples preguntas en una). Y esas preguntas deberían acabar cerradas cuanto antes. Luego también hay preguntas que no se ajustan pero podrían arreglarse y normalmente esas no reciben tantos votos de cierre por ser de usuarios nuevos.

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que, aunque seamos más pacientes con los usuarios nuevos (en general creo que la comunidad lo es), hay que seguir siendo estrictos con todos los usuarios por igual (nuevos y no tan nuevos) pero revisando las publicaciones caso por caso. Desde la experiencia: el contenido malo atrae contenido malo. Las malas preguntas atraen malas respuestas y otras malas preguntas (por parte del mismo usuario o de otros).

Comment: Lo entiendo, aunque discrepo respecto al cierre inmediato *(opinión claro, siempre tratamos de apegarnos a las normas)*, ya que incluso el usuario mismo es quien puede hacerlo en cuanto asuma su error. Una persona aprende más aceptando sus errores y actuando sobre los mismos. Tratamos de mantener el sitio a rajatabla, y en este caso creo que la tolerancia influye mucho.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo 100% en que hay que ser tolerantes y tener más paciencia con los usuarios nuevos. Es esencial. Pero es un problema más complejo de lo que parece: tener más paciencia no significa que haya que dar carta blanca para que se haga lo que se quiera, y mantener contenido malo perjudica a la comunidad en general. Por otra parte, los usuarios nuevos pueden traer nuevo conocimiento y beneficiar a la comunidad con sus preguntas/respuestas. Es una línea muy fina y no es fácil.

Comment: Como nota.. fijate que todos los usuarios pueden ver la ultima conexion de cada otro usuario. En este caso, OP volvio al sitio. no leyo ni uno de los enlaces que pasamos. hizo caso omiso a contestar los comentarios. Simplemente, querian que le hagan el ejercicio. Te das cuenta cuando tienen un ejercicio y estan trabados, y cuando solo quieren la resolucion del mismo....

Comment: El mensaje de cierre les dice que pueden editar la pregunta y mejorarla. Lo que sí debe pasar es que les demos realimentación en los comentarios para que entiendan qué pasa. Si no responden a eso, igual nos ahorramos la mugre de las preguntas sin esfuerzo. Ya me han tocado los "a la próxima sigo las normas, ¿tienes la respuesta?". E igual, siempre comienzo por los comentarios estándar y, al rato, si siguen sin cambiar nada y aplica un motivo de cierre, se vota el cierre

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vote para cerrarla, lo mismo que otra, de un compañero de curso, que preguntó exactamente lo mismo: [Silabas programa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460479/silabas-programa)

La razón para cerrarla es que el OP está simplemente pidiendo que le escriban el código, sin haber aportado ni una línea propia. No tiene que ver con la formulación de la pregunta.

Intentar dialogar con ellos es perder el tiempo. Como veras, ni siquiera han dado respuesta a los comentarios.

#### Respecto a las preguntas *mal formuladas*

No soy partidario de *castigar* automáticamente las preguntas mal formuladas. Lo mejor es juzgar la pregunta en su mérito, sin importar los aspectos formales.

Mi criterio es que si el OP **muestra** real esfuerzo y trabajo, hay que ayudarlo a formular bien la pregunta (completando código, ejemplos, aclarando detalles) vía comentarios.

Si el OP se ha esforzado, al menos tendrá una cierta comprensión del problema, desde el cual elaborar una respuesta.

En cambio, si el OP no se ha esforzado, no tendrá comprensión del problema. No hay por donde empezar a explicarle una solución, y es poco probable que entienda. Simplemente le habremos hecho la tarea.